# Debug WCF service locally from another application

Tags: .net, wcf

I have already checked a couple of posts on SO. I have a slight confusion on debugging the WCF on local system.

I have two solutions:

1. WCF service itself
2. Windows Console Application which consumes this service.

In local system IIS is installed. I ran the WCF application and message shown "Service hosted on IIS".

Now I want to debug the other application. I ran that application as well from VS. I want to debug methods in both, WCF and application.

I want to know whether this way, I can debug WCF application or there is any other better way to debug. Can it be installed as a Windows Service or only IIS is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can host WCF services on IIS, within a Windows Service or even in your applications (WinForms, WPF, Console).
But this has nothing to do with your requirement about debugging.

If you want to debug a running process on your local machine, you can [attach the debugger to another process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019) or you have to look for [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019) if that process runs on another machine.

But since you have the client and server code in your Visual Studio, why not start both applications together?

- If you have two solutions, you can launch one Visual Studio instance for the client solution and another Visual Studio for the server solution. Then press F5 in both of them.
- It is even easier if you have both projects in one solution: Simply change your solution settings to have [multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019) and hit F5.

Either way, you can debug your client and server code locally.

Comment: You mean, I have to open two instances of VS. In one, I have to run WCF application and in the other I have to run Console Application. Is this correct? In this case is it required to attach to the process?

Comment: Yes, correct. It is not necessary to attach to a process in that case.

Comment: I executed both, but the breakpoints in WCF not hitting. In Console application app.config, the endpoint is defined with a localhost url. I believe this is not pointing to the correct service.

Comment: Localhost should be correct. Have you double checked the port? Have you started both in Debug mode or in Release mode?

Comment: I have a question. The console application has a service reference to a folder which has published files of the WCF application. I guess this is the reason why it is not hitting the breakpoint. I want to know how to add a reference to WCF application in console application to be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way( and easiest that I can think of Debugging the WCF service if you have both project for them is this

1. Create a new Solution(or just use an existing VS solution)
2. Add both the WCF service Project and Console Project to the
   service(Can be run on different instances though)
3. Set the Console App to be the main startup application
4. Add a Service Reference to the Console App(and click the discover
   locally button)
5. This will create a Service Reference with the Service Library
   created
6. Then just run the methods from the console APP and it will hit your
   Service BreakPoints

Comment: On digging further in the console application, I found the Service Reference, which points to: http://localhost/xyz. But in my local system, this xyz folder is not there, neither inside inetpub\wwwroot or outside. I cloned this code from server. In server, this xyz folder exists under intetpub\wwwroot. To fix this, I published the local WCF service to local IIS. I created a new virtual application under Default Site and set the physical file path to inetpub\wwwroot but getting "Internal Server Error".

Comment: Why not use IIS Express?

Comment: Do I need to install it or it comes bundled with VS ?

Comment: It comes standard with VS, if you look at your WCF project there should be a web section in project properties, just change that to IIS Express(then you dont need the full IIS)